# Where to find Kubernetes API credentials with AKS?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service

I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/azure.md) to setting up a K8s cluster with external-dns' Azure DNS provider. 
The guide states that:

> When your Kubernetes cluster is created by ACS, a file named `/etc/kubernetes/azure.json` is created to store the Azure credentials for API access. Kubernetes uses this file for the Azure cloud provider.

When I create a cluster using aks (e.g. `az aks create --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myK8sCluster --node-count 1 --generate-ssh-keys`) this file doesn't exist.

Where do the API credentials get stored when using AKS?

Essentially I'm trying to work out where to point this command:

`kubectl create secret generic azure-config-file --from-
file=/etc/kubernetes/azure.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see when using AKS the `/etc/kubernetes/azure.json` doesn't get created. As an alternative I followed the instructions for use with non Azure hosted sites and created a service principal (https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/azure.md#optional-create-service-principal)

Creating the service principal produces some json that contains most of the detail. This can be used to manually create the azure.json file and the secret can be created from it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to get credentials:

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myK8sCluster
```

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough

Comment: Running this command looks like it downloads something to /home/{name}/.kube/config  Looking at the content of this it doesn't look like the json specified in the walkthrough. It is still possible to create the secret from this file and have it work. i.e. will "kubectl create secret generic azure-config-file --from-
file=/home/{name}/.kube/config" work ?

Comment: Have done. I can follow that guide with no trouble. I’m trying to integrate with the external-dns service that I linked to in my original question. I need to try and surface the information created by following the steps in your guide to external-dns

Comment: I think I’ve solved this by creating a service principal to get the details

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this command ?

```
cat ~/.kube/config
```

It provided all i needed for my CI to connect to the Kubernetes Cluster and use API